# App crashes while KIF tests running and no failure reported

Tags: ios, jenkins, kif-framework, kif

I am working with a CI system, Jenkins, that calls a script to launch automated KIF tests on our iOS application.

While running, the application crashes because of an uncaught exception in our code in `-[KIFTestActor runBlock:complete:timeout]`.

Unfortunately, no error is reported by the automated KIF tests, and so Jenkins incorrectly reports that the automated testing was a success. I had thought that perhaps `abort()`, which is in the stackcrawl, was causing the application to exit without an error code, so I registered a handler to catch uncaught exceptions and called `_exit(-1)` to make sure we were returning an error code. That was able to catch the exception and call `_exit(-1)`, but the Jenkins job still thinks that everything passed.

Has anyone dealt with this before and figured how to deal with this?

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692691/running-automation-tests-on-ios-application-continuously-even-after-crash) post to which no one has not yet responded.

This is how we launch the tests:

`xcodebuild clean test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -destination OS=latest,name="iPhone Retina (4-inch)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way we solved this was by parsing the output of the xcodebuild test command.

Thanks to the [post](http://www.leonardoborges.com/writings/2012/05/03/build-automation-with-xcode-4-dot-3-kif-and-jenkins/) by Leonardo Borges.